# Strange error with mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

```
app.get('/showme', function (req, res){

    console.log(req.session.user);

     UserModel.findOne({ user: req.session.user }, function (err, user){

     if (err) throw err;

         console.log(user);
         res.send('Look');

     });

});
```

When this is executed, I received correctly the user in the terminal, but, after that, suddenly the app crashed, and this is the error `TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of null`. The `req.session.user` is defined, and in the app. This is not the first time `UserModel.findOne({ user: req.session.user }` called, but is the only one that returns this error! Why this happen?

EDITED:

And this is the user's schema

```
var userschema = new mongoose.Schema({

   user: String,
   pass: String,
   mail: String,
   avatar: String,

});
```

EDITED:

I don't know why, but I don't get any error with `UserModel.find()`. It only happens with `UserModel.findOne()`.

EDITED:

```
app.get('/showme', function (req, res){

  UserModel.find({ user: req.session.user }, function (err, user){ 

    for (var i = 0; i <= user[0].following.length; i++) {

       UserModel.find({ _id: user[0].following[i] }, function (err, users){

              var userss = [];
              users[i] = users[i];
              console.log(users);  

        });

     }   

 });

 res.send('Hello');

});
```

And in this code, the first time `UserModel` doesn't returns any error, but the second does! 
This is what i received in the terminal:

```
[ { __v: 2,
   _id: 50e1d852d7b6f9e1be000003,
   avatar: './users/rodridev/full_Mgs-solid-snake.jpg',
   user: 'rodridev',
   notification: [],
   followers: [ '50e1cfda6e63107eb6000003' ],
   following: [ '50e1cfda6e63107eb6000003' ],
  ,
  ,
  undefined ]
  [ , , , undefined ]
  [ { __v: 1,
   _id: 50e214171553600000000003,
    avatar: './users/kirbo/8816.masterchief.jpg-610x0.jpg',
    user: 'kirbo',
    followers: [ '50e1cfda6e63107eb6000003' ],
    following: [],
    imagen: [] },
 ,
 ,
 undefined ]
```

And this is the error that appears down this. The same as before: `TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of null`

Comment: It would help to know how the `UserModel` schema is defined and the value of `req.session.user`.

Comment: i only store the user id in the session, not the entire user object.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
UserModel.findOne({ _id: req.session.user._id }, function (err, user) {
```

The problem is that you are asking for a user who has a property called `user` whose value is the current user. What you really want (I assume) is the user item from the database that is the current session user.

Alternatively, even better, is I like to do

```
UserModel.findById(req.session.user._id, function (err, user) {
```